# ORACLE SQL | If a column contains a value, then it will exclude a different value from the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that returns the data below it

```
select LISTAGG(d.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD) as value
from test_table d;

VALUE
---------
CI,ECI,POA
```

now I'm trying to add a condition whenever 'ECI' value is present, it should exclude 'CI' in the result like this one below

```
VALUE
---------
ECI,POA
```

I tried using case statement in where condition it prompted an error

```
select LISTAGG(d.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD, ',')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD) as value
from test_table d
where CASE d.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD
WHEN 'ECI' THEN d.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD <> 'CI'
END;


ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 36
```

is there any other way I could resolve this?

Comment: Skip the case attempt, simply use AND / OR instead.

Comment: It should be `where case blahblah end <> 'CI'`. But as jarlh said, you don't need a `case` expression here.

Comment: Hello @BryanjanicoVentura did any of this answers helped you ? If they did you an accept it or comment  it...

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps; read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, document_type_cd) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select 1, 'ECI' from dual union all
  5     select 1, 'CI'  from dual union all
  6     select 1, 'POA' from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 2, 'CI'  from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'POA' from dual union all
 10     --
 11     select 3, 'XYZ' from dual union all
 12     select 3, 'ABC' from dual
 13    ),
```

---

```
 14  temp as
 15    -- see whether CI and ECI exist per each ID
 16    (select id,
 17       sum(case when document_type_cd = 'CI' then 1 else 0 end) sum_ci,
 18       sum(case when document_type_cd = 'ECI' then 1 else 0 end) sum_eci
 19     from test
 20     group by id
 21    ),
 22  excl as
 23    -- exclude CI rows if ECI exist for that ID
 24    (select a.id,
 25            a.document_type_cd
 26     from test a join temp b on a.id = b.id
 27     where a.document_type_cd <> case when b.sum_ci > 0 and b.sum_eci > 0 then 'CI'
 28                                      else '-1'
 29                                 end
 30    )
 31  -- finally:
 32  select e.id,
 33         listagg(e.document_type_cd, ',') within group (order by e.document_type_cd) result
 34  from excl e
 35  group by e.id;

        ID RESULT
---------- --------------------
         1 ECI,POA
         2 CI,POA
         3 ABC,XYZ

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select LISTAGG(d.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD, ',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY D.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD) as value
from test_table d, 
(select sum (case when DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD = 'CI' then 1 else 0 end) C
from test_table) A
where d.DOCUMENT_TYPE_CD <> case when A.c > 0 then 'CI' when A.c = 0 then ' ' end;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fcfa00cba8034be26e1e9514e00e91ff)

Answer (score 0):

You may identify the presence of both the values with two conditional aggregations in the same `group by` and then replace `CI` inside the result of `listagg` in one pass.

> ```
> with a(id, cd) as (
> select 1, 'ABC' from dual union all
> select 1, 'ECI' from dual union all
> select 1, 'CI'  from dual union all
> select 1, 'POA' from dual union all
> select 2, 'XYZ' from dual union all
> select 2, 'ECI' from dual union all
> select 2, 'CI'  from dual union all
> select 2, 'POA' from dual union all
> select 3, 'CI'  from dual union all
> select 3, 'POA' from dual union all
> select 4, 'ABC' from dual union all
> select 4, 'DEF' from dual
> )
> select
>   id,
>   ltrim(
>     /*Added comma in case CI will be at the beginning*/
>     replace(
>       ',' || listagg(cd, ',') within group (order by cd asc),
>       decode(
>         /*If both are present, then replace CI. If not, then do not replace anything*/
>         max(decode(cd, 'CI', 1))*max(decode(cd, 'ECI', 1)),
>         1,
>         ',CI,'
>       ),
>       ','
>     ),
>     ','
>   ) as res
> from a
> group by id
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | RES        
> -: | :----------
>  1 | ABC,ECI,POA
>  2 | ECI,POA,XYZ
>  3 | CI,POA     
>  4 | ABC,DEF
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6154103e8765e8d681645d67770a83f7)*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GROUP BY`, you can also use windowing (aka analytic) functions to check the presence of *ECI* per group (test data shamelessly stolen from @littlefoot):

```
with
  test (id, document_type_cd) as
    -- sample data
    (select 1, 'ECI' from dual union all
     select 1, 'CI'  from dual union all
     select 1, 'POA' from dual union all
     --
     select 2, 'CI'  from dual union all
     select 2, 'POA' from dual union all
     --
     select 3, 'XYZ' from dual union all
     select 3, 'ABC' from dual
    ),
  temp as
    (select id, 
       document_type_cd, 
       sum(case when document_type_cd = 'ECI' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as sum_eci
     from test
    )
 select a.id,
        listagg(a.document_type_cd, ',') within group (order by a.document_type_cd) result
     from temp a 
     where a.document_type_cd != 'CI' or sum_eci = 0
     group by a.id;
```